# Using results of aggregate to subset data in R

Tags: r, aggregate, outliers

I'm using the `mad` function in `R`'s `stats` package to identify outliers. Using `aggregate`, I can find the boundary values for each unique combination of factor levels like so:

```
require(stats)
set.seed(492)
y <- rnorm(2000)
x1 <- sample(letters[1:2], 2000,T)
x2 <- sample(letters[1:2], 2000,T)
df <- data.frame(y,x1,x2)

boundaries <- aggregate(df$y, list(df$x1, df$x2), function(x) cbind(median(x) 
+ (3*mad(x)), median(x) - (3*mad(x))))
```

Which gives:

```
+---------------------------------------+
|  Group.1 Group.2       x.1       x.2  |
+---------------------------------------+
| 1       a       a  2.875560 -2.809068 |
| 2       b       a  2.867109 -2.843691 |
| 3       a       b  3.137889 -2.960135 |
| 4       b       b  3.091169 -3.134296 |
+---------------------------------------+
```

`x.1` is the upper bound and `x.2` is the lower bound. I want to subset `df` so that outliers are removed for each combination of factor levels - for example in a.a, I wouldn't want any values above 2.88 or below -2.80 but for a.b I would want the upper cut-off to be 3.14 and the lower cut-off to be -2.96.

So far, I've tried using `by`, but it returns data frames that are 0 rows in  length:

```
by(df$y, list(df$x1, df$x2), function(x) df[which(df$y>(median(x) + (3*mad(x))) &     df$y<(median(x) - (3*mad(x)))),])
```

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Does "x.2" represent the lower cut-off too?

Comment: Yes, sorry! I'll clarify in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `plyr`. It uses the **split-apply-combine** paradigm. We first split the data frame into pieces using the columns `x1` and `x2`. For each piece `d` (which is a data frame), we compute the limits outside of which we will consider `y` an outlier, and then use logical indexing to return only those rows of `d` which are not outliers. Finally, `ddply` takes care of assembling all the subsetted pieces together into a single data frame.

```
library(plyr)
df2 = ddply(df, .(x1, x2), function(d){
  limits = median(d$y) + 3*c(-1, 1)*mad(d$y)
  d[(d$y - limits[1])*(limits[2] - d$y) > 0,]
})
```

Comment: I initially attempted to use `ddply`, but got nowhere. Thanks for the explanation, I understand how to use `plyr` a little better now.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you could use `merge` and then some standard subsetting. In the following, I've modified your `aggregate` statement to result in nicer names to make `merge` more straightforward. I've also used `do.call(data.frame, ...)` to flatten the matrix columns as columns in the aggregated `data.frame`.

```
boundaries <- aggregate(y ~ x1 + x2, df, function(x)
  cbind(median(x) + (3*mad(x)), median(x) - (3*mad(x))))
boundaries <- do.call(data.frame, boundaries)

out <- merge(df, boundaries)
head(out)
#   x1 x2          y     y.1       y.2
# 1  a  a -0.4003471 2.87556 -2.809068
# 2  a  a -0.5652717 2.87556 -2.809068
# 3  a  a  0.1185306 2.87556 -2.809068
# 4  a  a  1.2634333 2.87556 -2.809068
# 5  a  a  0.3585731 2.87556 -2.809068
# 6  a  a -0.1436202 2.87556 -2.809068

out2 <- out[with(out, y.2 < y & y < y.1), c("y", "x1", "x2")]
head(out2)
#            y x1 x2
# 1 -0.4003471  a  a
# 2 -0.5652717  a  a
# 3  0.1185306  a  a
# 4  1.2634333  a  a
# 5  0.3585731  a  a
# 6 -0.1436202  a  a

dim(out2)
# [1] 1993    3
```

Comment: `R` reports `Error in '[.default'(xj, i) : invalid subscript type 'closure'` when I try to initially create `boundaries`. Any idea what might be going on?

Comment: @luser, Is your actual `data.frame` called "df"? Do you have the same problem with this sample dataset that you posted?

Comment: My actual `data.frame` is not called `df` or any other system-reserved  name. I have the same problem when I clear my workspace and just copy-paste the code I put here.

Comment: @luser, What version of R are you using?

Comment: `sessionInfo()` reports 3.0.2

Comment: @luser, Not sure what to say. If your regular `aggregate` syntax works (not the formula approach I used), you can still use this solution by continuing from the `do.call(data.frame, ...)` step, but you'll have to either rename the columns in the result from `aggregate` or you'll have to specify the columns to use for merging in `merge`.

Answer (score 0):

This function filters values to satisfy your condition, structured to avoid unnecessary re-calculation of median and mad

```
filt <- function (x) {
    b <- median(x) + mad(x) * c(-3, 3)
    x[x > b[1] & x < b[2]]
}
```

Aggregate your original data frame, with the result column 'y' being a list-of-vectors satisfying the filter criterion

```
df1 <- aggregate(y ~ x1 + x2, df, filt, simplify=FALSE)
```

The indicator variables are then replicated, and the list-of-vectors unlisted, to  arrive at the final representation

```
len <- sapply(df1$y, length)
result <- data.frame(x1=rep(df1$x1, len), x2=rep(df1$x2, len),
                     y=unlist(df1$y, use.names=FALSE))
```